# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.loginpanel2/com.example.loginpanel2.MainActivity}:

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[image]

When I run my application, I get an "Application Stopped" error.

Comment: Did you change anything in `styles.xml`? Or did you set a custom theme anywhere?

Comment: I solved the problem, I fixed a mistake in theme.xml

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crash is caused by the theme of activity. If you are using AppCompatActivity You need to set...

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.YourTheme"
```

to your manifest(application or activity).

If your activity extends Activity, No need to add it to your manifest, and the crash will not happen.